# parsing json with rhomobile

Tags: json, rhomobile

i have a json data stream at http://mdata.taviatech.com.ng/mobiledb/topgainers
Can anyone give me sample code for to parse this to a page?

Also, is the json well formed?

thanks

Answer (score 4):

When trying to parse json in Rhodes, try with `Rho:JSON.parse(string)` instead of `JSON.parse(string)`. Hope That helps.

Comment: Is this documented somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

```
res = JSON.parse("[{\"count\":10},{\"version\":1},{\"total_count\":
5425},{\"token\": 123},{\"s\":\"RhoDeleteSource\",\"ol\":[{\"o\":
\"rho_del_obj\",\"av\":[{\"i\":55550425},{\"i\":75665819},{\"i\":
338165272},{\"i\":402396629},{\"i\":521753981},{\"i\":664143530},{\"i
\":678116186},{\"i\":831092394},{\"i\":956041217},{\"i\":
970452458}]}]}]")
```

[Parsing JSON response into ruby data structure.](http://groups.google.com/group/rhomobile/browse_thread/thread/58d483ac3d17c29/da9b3ab4e675effa?lnk=gst&q=json#da9b3ab4e675effa)

Comment: Sorry..i was supposed to state that i want to do this with rhomobile.

Answer (score 0):

require 'json' at the top of your controller file.

Then use Rho::AsyncHttp.get to fetch the JSON string.

In your callback parse the string like this:

```
$httpresult = @params['body']
$jsonresult = Rho::JSON.parse($httpresult)
```

BTW, if you are using JSONP you will need to strip out the callback function in the response string first.

If you are NOT using JSONP then Rho 3.3.X and higher should automatically dump the @params['body'] into a parsed JSON object for you.